# Prove $\lim_{x \to a}x^{0.6}=a^{0.6}$ using the calculus epsilon-delta definition of limit@@

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Let $a>0$. Prove

$$\lim_{x \to a}x^{0.6}=a^{0.6}$$

What I have done:

$$|x^{0.6}-a^{0.6}|=|x^{0.2}-a^{0.2}| \cdot |x^{0.4}+x^{0.2}a^{0.2}+a^{0.4}|$$

Then I am not sure how to continue, I don't know how to get rid of the complicated terms on the RHS

Anyone can help? appreciate!

Comment: @mfl can help with this?

Comment: @amWhy can help with this?urgent!

Comment: @Stef can help?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to continue this approach, you can write
\begin{align*}
|x^{0.6}-a^{0.6}| &= |x^{0.2}-a^{0.2}| \cdot |x^{0.4}+x^{0.2}a^{0.2}+a^{0.4}| \\
&= \frac{|x-a|}{|x^{0.8}+x^{0.6}a^{0.2}+x^{0.4}a^{0.4}+x^{0.2}a^{0.6}+a^{0.8}|} \cdot |x^{0.4}+x^{0.2}a^{0.2}+a^{0.4}|.
\end{align*}
The function $|x^{0.4}+x^{0.2}a^{0.2}+a^{0.4}|\big/|x^{0.8}+x^{0.6}a^{0.2}+x^{0.4}a^{0.4}+x^{0.2}a^{0.6}+a^{0.8}|$ is bounded for $x$ near $a$, and so by the squeeze theorem, the whole expression tends to $0$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: is there any easier to understand approach?@Greg Martin

Comment: can you finish the proof? I want to see how it is done. really confused

Comment: I do like yours for the next step and estimate the denominator <a^0.8 and my question is how to get rid of |x^0.4+x^0.2a^0.2+a^0.4| by estimation? thx for reply pls